# wp_query from 2 specific categories only

Tags: php, html, wordpress

We are doing a simple WP_Query to bring through posts that **must** have category ID 98 and 1 assigned to them - with no other categories. This is bringing through correctly, however it is also showing posts that have both category ID 98 & 1, but also assigned to multiple other categories.

We have tried:-

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type'   => 'notifications',
    'category__in' => array(1,98),
);
```

But this shows posts in them 2 categories, plus more categories.

Thank you

Comment: The purpose of `category__in` is just to find posts that are in _any_ of the given categories - no more, no less. `category__and` exists, to only select posts that are in _all_ of the given categories. _"with no other categories"_ - neither of the two on their own, can achieve that. You'd have to check if adding `category__not_in` - with the IDs of all your other categories, you will have to determine them upfront somehow, either static or dynamic - achieves the desired result; if not, you might need a more custom solution.

Comment: Do you have a solution? Really stuck on this

Comment: I suggested something to try first of all, didn't I? Do you have _feedback_?

Comment: Do you know the best way to fetch all category IDs in a WP_Query, excluding 1 & 98?

Comment: $omit_category_ids = 29;   

'tax_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
     'taxonomy' =>  'category',
     'field'    => 'slug',
     'operator' => 'IN',
     'terms' => 'all',
    ),    
    array(
     'taxonomy' => 'category',
     'field'    => 'slug',
     'terms'    => 'live',
     'operator' => 'IN',
    ),
    array(
     'taxonomy' => 'category',
     'field'    => 'term_id',
     'terms'    => $omit_category_ids,
     'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    ),    
   ),

so now, I need the best way to pass all category IDs in the $omit_category_ids

Comment: `get_categories` or `get_terms`, and then you'll have to extract the IDs, and remove the ones you _want_ the products to have.

Comment: I cant get this working, if you could help that would be amazing